# In Postgres, Confusion for the conversion of Numeric/Real/Double Precision to Character Varying / Text

Tags: postgresql

For the conversion of Numeric/Real/Double Precision to Character Varying / Text.

```
select (12.0/100)::Double Precision;# 0.12
select (12.0/100)::Double Precision::Text;# 0.119999999999999996
select 0.12::text ; # 0.12
select (12.0/100)::Numeric::Text ; #0.12000000000000000000
```

`0.12::text`  is correct, but the result of  `(12.0/100)::Numeric::Text` and `(12.0/100)::Double Precision::Text` are confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values might confuse you, but they are correct.

It seems like you set the parameter `extra_float_digits` to 3 (or you are using JDBC, which does that for you).

`double precision` is a floating point type and hence imprecise. With the default 0 for `extra_float_digits` you won't notice that, because the value is truncated so that only significant digits are shown, but if you request full precision, you'll see the rounding error in all its glory.

The last command will show many zeroes because you didn't specify `numeric(10,2)` to limit the number of decimal digits, and division potentially produces a lot of those. If you try `*` instead of `/`, you'll see what I mean.